# How to read hexadecimal registers from a Modbus RTU device using Python. for instance this hexadecimal string ([000A*65536]+000B)*008D*008E*0.01

Tags: python

I want to know how to read hexadecimal registers from a Modbus RTU device. How do I read for hexadecimal registers in a string suchas this `"([000A*65536]+000B)*008D*008E*0.01"`

such that 000A is a registers returning a value; 000B, 008D and 008E are  hexadecimal register.

It was not given right answer as expected. I am supposed to see a value same as what the Modbus RTU device is showing on the screen

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.